# Recursive function g(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have a function `g(n)` which can be given by `g(n)=f(n,n)`  . This is defined recursively                                                                                     by

```
f(i, j) = 1/3
(f(i−1, j) + f(i−1, j −1) + f(i, j −1))

with f(0,0) = 0;  f(i,0) = 1,i > 0; f(0, j) = 1, j > 0
```

I have written a java program to compute this for values from 10-15. The first couple of values are processed quickly but towards the end of values the program becomes very slow and takes a long time to process the result. Is there a problem with my code or is it just a lengthy calculation?

```
public class javaapplication4 {
    private static double f(double i, double j) {
        if (i == 0.0 && j == 0.0) return 0.0;
        if (i == 0.0 || j == 0.0) return 1.0;
        return (f(i - 1, j) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));
    }

    private static double g(double n) {
        return f(n, n);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for (int n = 10; n < 16; n ++) {
            System.out.println("g(" + (int) n + "): " + g(n));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code with a profiler such as YourKit? It looks fine to me, it shouldn't be all that intensive. Also, what kind of hardware are you running? Your CPU speed can have an influence as well.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? What error do you get?

Comment: Quantify slow.  Since your base case arrives at i=1, there will be 45 stack frames active when the base case  arrives

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you seem to have forgotten a `1.0 / 3` in this line:

> return (f(i - 1, j) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));

Second, your program is slow because the same values get computed multiple times. For example, `f(i - 1, j)` will call `f(i - 1, j - 1)`, which is also called from `f(i, j)`.

To solve this, either compute your recurrence relation in a matrix:

```
 f(0,0) = 0; f(i,0) = 1,i > 0; f(0, j) = 1, j > 0
 for i = 1 to n:
   for j = 1 to n:
     f[i, j] = 0.33*(f[i - 1, j] + f[i, j - 1] + f[i - 1, j - 1])
```

Or keep your recursive implementation, but use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to speed it up:

> A memoized function "remembers" the results corresponding to some set of specific inputs. Subsequent calls with remembered inputs return the remembered result rather than recalculating it, thus eliminating the primary cost of a call with given parameters from all but the first call made to the function with those parameters.

Basically, you can still use a matrix to store results in, and do something like this:

```
private static double f(double i, double j) { // make i and j ints, they do not need to be doubles here.
    if (i == 0.0 && j == 0.0) return 0.0;
    if (i == 0.0 || j == 0.0) return 1.0;
    if (storageMatrix[i, j] != -1) {
      return storageMatrix[i, j];
    }

    storageMatrix[i, j] = (1.0 / 3) * (f(i - 1, j) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));
    return storageMatrix[i, j];
}
```

You can optimize things even further by noticing that if you implement the iterative solution I gave pseudocode for above, you only ever use the current and previous rows of your matrix. So you can just use two arrays of length `n` instead of a square `n x n` matrix to compute your function.

Comment: This class of solutions is also known as [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to speed up with memoization.  Don't throw away the values that you've worked so hard to calculate.

Here's my output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\out\production\stack-overflow;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jxl.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jdom.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\Jama-1.0.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\commons-io-2.3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\sqlitejdbc-v056.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-xc-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\commons-lang3-3.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\commons-math3-3.3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-all-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\StackWrap4J-1.0.1.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-smile-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-mrbean-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-core-lgpl-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\postgresql-8.1-405.jdbc3.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\jackson-mapper-lgpl-1.6.2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.web-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.core-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.context-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\lib\org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.RC2.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\test-lib\junit-4.10.jar;F:\Projects\Java\stack-overflow\test-lib\org.springframework.test-3.1.0.RC2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain cruft.RecursionExample
n: 0 g(n): 0.00000015.5 + 
n: 1 g(n): 0.66666715.5 + 
n: 2 g(n): 0.81481515.5 + 
n: 3 g(n): 0.86419815.5 + 
n: 4 g(n): 0.88797415.5 + 
n: 5 g(n): 0.90240315.5 + 
n: 6 g(n): 0.91236115.5 + 
n: 7 g(n): 0.91977515.5 + 
n: 8 g(n): 0.92557415.5 + 
n: 9 g(n): 0.93027315.5 + 
n: 10 g(n): 0.93418015.5 + 
n: 11 g(n): 0.93749715.5 + 
n: 12 g(n): 0.94035715.5 + 
n: 13 g(n): 0.94285715.5 + 
n: 14 g(n): 0.94506715.5 + 
n: 15 g(n): 0.94703915.5 + 
total wall time:         11 ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Runs in 11 ms for me.

```
package cruft;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * RecursionExample description here
 * @author Michael
 * @link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933093/recursive-function-gn
 * @since 3/8/2015 7:28 PM
 */
public class RecursionExample {

    private static final Map<String, Double> memo = new HashMap<String, Double>();


    private static double f(int  i, int j) {
        if (i < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("i cannot be negative");
        if (j < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("j cannot be negative");
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) return 0.0;
        if (i == 0 || j == 0) return 1.0;
        String key = Integer.toString(i) + "~" + Integer.toString(j);
        if (memo.containsKey(key)) {
            return memo.get(key);
        } else {
            double value = (f(i-1, j) + f(i-1, j-1) + f(i, j-1))/3.0;
            memo.put(key, value);
            return value;
        }
    }

    private static double g(int n) {
        return f(n, n);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            for (int n = 0; n < 16; n ++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("n: %d g(n): %f15.5 + ", n, g(n)));
            }
        } finally {
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(String.format("total wall time: %10d ms", (endTime-begTime)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a string key seems wasteful. You can always do `n * i + j`.

Comment: I'll change the code and see if it improves on 11 ms.  I'm guessing it doesn't matter.  I think what I wrote is quite readable.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to divide your result by 3, otherwise your code is fine. You can speed it up for an arbitrary amount of values by adding an array that previous results are saved in, I did it like this:

```
public class Recursivity {

static double[][] results = new double[20][20];

private static double f(int i, int j) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
        return 1.0;
    }
    if (results[i][j] != -1.0) {
        return (results[i][j]);

    }
    double output = (f(i - 1, j) + (f(i - 1, j - 1) + (f(i, j - 1))));
    results[i][j] = output;
    return output;

}

private static double g(int n) {
    return f(n, n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
            results[i][j] = -1.0;
        }
    }

    for (int n = 10; n < 16; n++) {

        System.out.println("g(" + (int) n + "): " + g(n));

    }
}

}
```

This runs a lot faster, but it requires you to have Integers as input for f. I don't know if there is any kind of list you can index by non-discrete numbers, but it should be possible for a finite amount of them.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer above, suppose a system can compute f(k, k) in time t.  To compute f(k+1,k+1), it's going to have to compute f(k, k+1), f(k, k) and f(k+1, k). That's going to take about 3 times as long. In other words, for any given k, the time to compute f(k+1,k+1) is triple that of f(k,k). This gets out of hand fast: computing f(15, 15) is going to take 243 times as long as computing f(10, 10)!

Answer (score -1):

your code is good but you just forgot to add 1/3 to  here ;

```
    return (f(i - 1, j) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));
```

so it should be like this ;

```
    return (f(i - 1, j)*0.33 + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));
```

or 
        return (f(i - 1, j)*(1/3) + f(i - 1, j - 1) + f(i, j - 1));